# JavaMail API attachment cannot be last record of multipart

Tags: java, android, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail api to develop my android app to send a mail with attachment. However, I discover that if the attachment is the last record of the multipart, then the mail cannot be delivered to the destination. I have no idea why this happen, and I have search there does not have similar question discussing on this issue. So I open this question and would like to seek answer from experts here.

my code segment for sending the mail:

```
public boolean send(String[] toAddress, String fromAddress, String subject,
                    String body, String filename) throws Exception { 
    Properties props = setProperties(); 

    try{ 
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 
        session.setDebug(true); 

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress)); 

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[toAddress.length]; 
        for(int i=0; i<toAddress.length; i++){ 
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(toAddress[i]); 
        } 

        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 
        msg.setSubject(subject); 
        msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 


        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        messageBodyPart1.setText(body); 
        multi.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1); 

        BodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
        messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
        messageBodyPart2.setFileName("record.csv"); 
        multi.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

        BodyPart messageBodyPart3 = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        messageBodyPart3.setText(""); 
        multi.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart3);

        msg.setContent(multi); 

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp"); 
        transport.connect(host, 25, user, password); 
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients()); 
        transport.close(); 
        return true; 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Log messages display:

Does not have bodypart3:

```
08-16 15:09:33.337: I/System.out(6314): EHLO localhost
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): 250-web.mysmtp.com Hello localhost [202.155.209.250]
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): 250-SIZE 52428800
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): 250-PIPELINING
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): 250-STARTTLS
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): 250 HELP
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
08-16 15:09:33.345: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
08-16 15:09:33.353: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
08-16 15:09:33.353: I/System.out(6314): AUTH LOGIN
08-16 15:09:33.361: I/System.out(6314): 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
08-16 15:09:33.361: I/System.out(6314): Y2xpZW50YWxlcnRzQHVuaXNlcnZlaXQuY29t
08-16 15:09:33.368: I/System.out(6314): 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
08-16 15:09:33.368: I/System.out(6314): cEBzc3cwcmQhIUA=
08-16 15:09:33.384: I/System.out(6314): 235 Authentication succeeded
08-16 15:09:33.392: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
08-16 15:09:33.392: I/System.out(6314): MAIL FROM:<me@mysmtp.com>
08-16 15:09:33.415: I/System.out(6314): 250 OK
08-16 15:09:33.415: I/System.out(6314): RCPT TO:<you@mysmtp.com>
08-16 15:09:33.470: I/System.out(6314): 250 Accepted
08-16 15:09:33.470: I/System.out(6314): RCPT TO:<admin@mysmtp.com>
08-16 15:09:33.478: I/System.out(6314): 250 Accepted
08-16 15:09:33.478: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
08-16 15:09:33.478: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP:   you@mysmtp.com
08-16 15:09:33.478: I/System.out(6314): DEBUG SMTP:   admin@mysmtp.com
08-16 15:09:33.478: I/System.out(6314): DATA
08-16 15:09:33.486: I/System.out(6314): 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314): Date: Thu, 16 Aug 2012 15:09:30 +0800 (HKT)
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314): From: me@mysmtp.com
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314): To: you@mysmtp.com, admin@mysmtp.com
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314): Message-ID: <1099216984.1.1345100973553.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314): Subject: Record cannot be inserted!
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314): MIME-Version: 1.0
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314): Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314):     boundary="----=_Part_0_1098789192.1345100970404"
08-16 15:09:33.564: I/System.out(6314): 
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): ------=_Part_0_1098789192.1345100970404
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): 
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): Please insert manually!
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): ------=_Part_0_1098789192.1345100970404
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=record.csv
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=record.csv
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): 
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): ABC,HK,A,2012/08/16 10:02, ,
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): 
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): ------=_Part_0_1098789192.1345100970404--
08-16 15:09:33.571: I/System.out(6314): .
08-16 15:09:33.611: I/System.out(6314): 250 OK id=1T1uCu-0007Fx-Tu
08-16 15:09:33.611: I/System.out(6314): QUIT
08-16 15:09:33.618: I/System.out(6314): 221 web.mysmtp.com closing connection
```

Has bodypart3:

```
08-16 15:12:34.353: I/System.out(6876): EHLO localhost
08-16 15:12:34.361: I/System.out(6876): 250-web.mysmtp.com Hello localhost [202.155.209.250]
08-16 15:12:34.361: I/System.out(6876): 250-SIZE 52428800
08-16 15:12:34.361: I/System.out(6876): 250-PIPELINING
08-16 15:12:34.361: I/System.out(6876): 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
08-16 15:12:34.361: I/System.out(6876): 250-STARTTLS
08-16 15:12:34.361: I/System.out(6876): 250 HELP
08-16 15:12:34.368: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
08-16 15:12:34.368: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
08-16 15:12:34.368: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
08-16 15:12:34.368: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
08-16 15:12:34.368: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
08-16 15:12:34.368: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
08-16 15:12:34.368: I/System.out(6876): AUTH LOGIN
08-16 15:12:34.384: I/System.out(6876): 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
08-16 15:12:34.384: I/System.out(6876): Y2xpZW50YWxlcnRzQHVuaXNlcnZlaXQuY29t
08-16 15:12:34.392: I/System.out(6876): 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
08-16 15:12:34.392: I/System.out(6876): cEBzc3cwcmQhIUA=
08-16 15:12:34.400: I/System.out(6876): 235 Authentication succeeded
08-16 15:12:34.415: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
08-16 15:12:34.415: I/System.out(6876): MAIL FROM:<me@mysmtp.com>
08-16 15:12:34.431: I/System.out(6876): 250 OK
08-16 15:12:34.431: I/System.out(6876): RCPT TO:<you@mysmtp.com>
08-16 15:12:34.470: I/System.out(6876): 250 Accepted
08-16 15:12:34.470: I/System.out(6876): RCPT TO:<admin@mysmtp.com>
08-16 15:12:34.486: I/System.out(6876): 250 Accepted
08-16 15:12:34.486: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
08-16 15:12:34.486: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP:   you@mysmtp.com
08-16 15:12:34.486: I/System.out(6876): DEBUG SMTP:   admin@mysmtp.com
08-16 15:12:34.486: I/System.out(6876): DATA
08-16 15:12:34.493: I/System.out(6876): 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Date: Thu, 16 Aug 2012 15:12:32 +0800 (HKT)
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): From: me@mysmtp.com
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): To: you@mysmtp.com, admin@mysmtp.com
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Message-ID: <1099235248.1.1345101154551.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Subject: Record cannot be inserted!
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): MIME-Version: 1.0
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876):     boundary="----=_Part_0_1098789960.1345101152034"
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): 
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): ------=_Part_0_1098789960.1345101152034
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): 
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Please insert manually!
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): ------=_Part_0_1098789960.1345101152034
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=record.csv
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=record.csv
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): 
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): ABC,HK,A,2012/08/16 10:02, ,
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): 
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): ------=_Part_0_1098789960.1345101152034
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): 
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): 
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): ------=_Part_0_1098789960.1345101152034--
08-16 15:12:34.571: I/System.out(6876): .
08-16 15:12:34.587: I/System.out(6876): 250 OK id=1T1uFp-0007Ka-TP
08-16 15:12:34.587: I/System.out(6876): QUIT
08-16 15:12:34.603: I/System.out(6876): 221 web.mysmtp.com closing connection
```

If I remove messageBodyPart3, then I will not able to receive my mail. May I ask what is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

That third part is completely gratuitous, it shouldn't make any difference.  Well, really, it shouldn't be there at all.  Unless it changes whether your server thinks the message is spam or not.

In any event, you need to supply more information than "not able to receive".

Is the message accepted by your SMTP server?

Does your SMTP server send it to the destination server?

Does the destination server store it in your mailbox?

Are you able to see it in your mailbox using any mail reader?

Comment: May be I can show your the logs, then it will make it easlier for you to recognize the problem.